# Copying an NSDictionary without empty values?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, row, nsdictionary

I'm trying to create an `NSDictionary` with the `dictionaryWithDictionary` method.  However, my first `NSDictionary` A may have some keys with empty values.  How can I create B that doesn't have any keys with empty values?  I'm doing all of this for the purposes of populating a `UITableView` with rows that correspond to each non-empty key in the `NSDictionary`.

Comment: What's an "empty value" in this case? NSDictionary doesn't allow `nil` values.

Comment: A key with a variable that's a blank.

Comment: That still does not help, a dictionary's values could be anything, NSString, NSNumber, even your own custom classes. If a dictionary does not contain a value for a particular key, then `objectForKey:` returns `nil`. If your values are zero-length strings or `[NSNull null]` values, then let us know. There's not really any such thing as a "blank variable" in Cocoa.

Comment: I have a set of dictionaries that all have the same keys in my property list.  I entered values for some of the keys.  In other keys I did not enter anything for their values.  Yet the key exists, I can see it in my p-list.  So what is its value if I hadn't entered anything into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *destDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[sourceDictionary count]];
NSEnumerator *keyEnumerator = [[sourceDictionary allKeys] objectEnumerator];
id key;
while ( key = [keyEnumerator nextObject] )
    {
    NSString *object = [sourceDictionary objectForKey:key];
    if ([object length] == 0)
        continue;
    [destDictionary setObject:object forKey:key];
    }
```

Comment: Oops. 'object' started out as 'value' in my code example - and I neglected to change all 'value' to 'object'. Sample now fixed. You could say (object == nil) instead of (!object), if you'd prefer.

Comment: Excellent example!  Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work.  I guess the object exists as long as the key exists, even though the values are all sent to blank ("").  I'm not sure how to get around that.

Comment: Updated again. Also, @quixoto makes good point - which I had overlooked - that object can't be nil.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a block test, filtering out the keys whose values have a length and create your new dictionary from that.

```
NSSet *keySet = [dictionary keysOfEntriesPassingTest:
                 ^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                   return (BOOL)[obj length];
                 }];

NSArray *keys = [keySet allObjects];
NSArray *nonEmptyObjects = [dictionary objectsForKeys:keys notFoundMarker:@""];
NSDictionary *newDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:nonEmptyObjects
                                                    forKeys:keys];
```