# What is a blank value in a property list considered as when fed into NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, parsing, plist, nsdictionary, null

Say I have a property list that I store into an `NSDictionary`.  An example output from `NSLog` follows:

```
2010-12-05 15:26:26.631 TestApp[598:207] Test contents: {
Address = "";
Name = "Test Dictionary";
```

What exactly would the value for Address be considered?  I have heard many possibilities, but I'm not sure exactly.  Is it `NSNull`, `nil`, what?  What I would ultimately like to do is to create a second `NSDictionary` that filters out all of these blank values, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350742/copying-an-nsdictionary-without-empty-values).  But first, I need to figure out what the blank value is counted as, so then I can parse my plist for them, and then discount the keys associated with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty string is a string, not NSNull or nil.  So one way to test would be `[@"" isEqualToString: thevalue]`.